# Why is the output different in the two cases?

Tags: java, field, shadowing, member-hiding

Why is the output different in the below case even when, the variable has been overridden?

```
public class A {
    int a = 500;

    void get() {
        System.out.println("a is " + this.a);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    int a = 144;
}

public class mainmethod {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B ob = new B();
        System.out.println("a is " + ob.a);
        ob.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called "field hiding" or "shadowing". See more questions (and answers) on it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+field+hiding http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+field+shadowing

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: You need to remember one simple rule: "fields are not polymorphic". Polymorphism (late/dynamic binding) works only for methods which are not static/final/private.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as overridden variables. `B` actually has *two* instance variables named `a`: one it declares and another it inherits. See this:

```
B ob = new B();
System.out.println("B.a is " + ob.a);
System.out.println("A.a is " + ((A)ob).a);
```

Inside a `B`'s instance method you can write `super.a` or `((A)this).a` to access the parent's variable.

Comment: The funny (and frnkly rather confusing to beginners) part is printing this in get() gives you B@XXX

Comment: Slightly confusing, but also correct: `B` has both those variables and it's all about name resolution rules which one you'll access without qualification. But the bottom line is: _don't do it_.

Comment: But in the local variable table of byte code you can see that signature of `this` is `LA`

Comment: Sure, because it's declared in `A`. The static type of `this` is certainly `A`.

Comment: `this.a` is changing based on `this` yet, `this` will print the same thing in `A` ^--^

Comment: Of course, just like with static members. `this.a` does not dispatch against the runtime type of `this`.

Comment: Ok.. That makes sense. Then probably, they should return `A@XX` instead of `B@XXX` when we are in `A`.

Comment: No because `toString()` is an instance method wihch does dispatch against the runtime type. What you're suggesting is that the behavior of `toString()` should change depedning on call site. That would be very undesirable.

Comment: Ya. That's true. Yet, this model somehow seems broken / incomplete :)

Comment: Not to me---there is one well-defined mechanism of dynamically dispatched instance method calls. It cannot be consistently extended to dynamic dispatch of instance field access because the former is behavior and the latter is data. Data is never polymorphic, only behavior can be.

Comment: *Data is never polymorphic, only behavior is* - Ok. This sums it up. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing `ob.a`, you get the variable `int a` from your `ob` object, which is object of the class `B`.

However, when you do `ob.get();`, you are calling the `get()`-method from class `A`, because there is no `get()` in `B`, which - as you wrote - uses `this.a`, which would be the `int a` of class `A` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

No the variable is not overridden.
`ob.a`
print the a variable of B class.
`ob.get()`
searches for the get method in B class.when it does not gets there it then searches the parent class and executes it.